# how to modify the nav vales of a second page without affecting the index page nav

Tags: html, css

I am relatively inexperienced with HTML and CSS and I am having a spot of difficulty trying to change the padding and margin values of my navigation bar on a second page without it affecting the index page.

NB: I want to style the nav slightly different on the second page.

I have 2 navigation bars `.navbar` and `.navbar2` each with identical code.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <nav class="large clearfix">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="famous.html">Famous People</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="places.html">Places to Visit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="veggieburger"><a href="#nav">&equiv;</a></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

How do I call out `navbar2` UL LI properties from a syntactical perspective in the CSS in order to style it different without affecting the navigation values aligned to the index page.

I have tried without success in the CSS.

```
.navbar2  > li {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: no need to write like [.navbar2  > li]. only write [.navbar2  li] and it will work. learn about css selectors over here. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for managing different classes (.), and IDs (#), we use these selectors in the brackets I've written in.

Say for example you want to style navbar and navbar2 independently, you would directly style them differently by using the selector ".". Just add a "." in front of the class, and apply your properties as needed.

So for example, imagine my HTML is all done up, this would be the CSS:

```
.navbar
        {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30vw;
        color: red;     /*this would make the text red*/
        }

.navbar2
        {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30vw;
        color: green    /*and this makes the text green*/
        }
```

Hope that helped!